# Mahout Recommendations based on demographic information

Tags: mahout

For an e-commerce application, as soon as user login to app, i need to recommend the products based on user demographic information like age, location, gender.

I am familiar with mahout user based and item based recommendations. but for the given requirement these are not suitable.

Which mahout algorithm can be used for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use K means clustering algorithm and according the the cluster information, system can recommend products.

Please refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/K-Means+Clustering)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: OK, So with K means clustering, all the products will be clustered to different groups based on demographic information. So we will have groups for location,age and Gender. But if we need the product recommendation based on combination of age, location and gender then how K means helps ?

Comment: Yes. It can be achieved. Your input file may have multiple features like age, location etc. R could help you in applying K-Means clustering on multiple features. Apache Mahout implementation overwrite features instead of applying multiple features. And when you apply clustering on these multiple features, clusters would be formed based on all features instead of one.  However, I am not sure about the use-case, So I am just discussing technical feasibility here. You may need to apply based on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

For that i guess combination of clustering and classification will sort out your issue.

Say 
A{x,y,z}
B{a,b,c}

We have two model A and B generated from training data set.In simple word two clusters A and B.With x,y,z and a,b,c users respectively.

Now a new user say **p** log in.

We randomly pick up one user from both A and B cluster.And calculate it distance from the new user who just logs in.

Suppose 
p-y < p-c (We have to use a specific distance measure for real case)

so p should be placed in cluster A.

Hope this helps